# Viewing Data from two tables while linking multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to set up a view in a database I want to see all the data in the PERSON table and three columns from the NON_PERSONNEL table for a program from the PROGRAM table.  This is what I am trying now, the query runs without errors but doesnt give me any results. All 4 of the tables listed below are imperative to derive the answer

```
SELECT 
    person.*, 
    non_personnel.description, 
    non_personnel.amount
FROM 
    person, 
    non_personnel, 
    personnel_role, 
    programs
WHERE 
    person.person_id = personnel_role.person_id
    AND personnel_role.program_id = programs.program_id
    AND programs.program_id = non_personnel.program_id
    AND programs.program_name = 'Fake Program'
```

Comment: Use `Left Join` on other tables with person table, @RADAR answer should work for you

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on your schema and the data in the tables. The way you have it written now means that only records that match in every table (according to your WHERE conditions) are passed into the result set.

This means that you have to have all `program_id's` in your `programs` table that you want returned in the results ALSO in your `non_personnel` table. They must also ALL be in your `personnel_role` table. And all `person_ids` in your `personnel_role` table must be in the `person` table. You get no results back, so this is probably not what you meant to write.

My guess is that you want to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` here. `LEFT OUTER JOIN` says "Take all records from one table and ONLY records from the joined table that meet the criteria in your ON statement".

Because you are wanting information based on a particular Program, chances are you want to start with that table:

```
SELECT person.*,
    non_personnel.description,
    non_personnel.amount
FROM 
    programs
    LEFT OUTER JOIN personnel_role ON
        programs.program_id = personnel_role.program_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN person ON
        personnel_role.person_id = person.person_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN non_personnel
        programs.program_id = non_personnel.program_id
WHERE
    programs.program_name = 'Fake Program'
```

This is a bit of an assumption since I have no idea what your schema is or how your data is built, but I'm betting it's what you are after.

What this `FROM` clause says is:
1. Take all records from `Program` (where `program_name` = 'fake program') and only reocrds from `personnel_role` that share the same `program_id`
2. Take only the records from `person` where the `person_id` matches the records we just got from the `personnel_role` table
3. Take only the records from `non_personnel` where it shares a program_id with the results from the `program` table.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `left join`, so you get all persons but description and amount can be NULL if that person doesn't have records in other tables

Also use explicit join syntax.

```
SELECT person.*, non_personnel.description, non_personnel.amount
FROM person
left join personnel_role
ON person.person_id = personnel_role.person_id
left join programs
ON personnel_role.program_id = programs.program_id
AND programs.program_name = 'Fake Program' 
left join non_personnel
ON programs.program_id = non_personnel.program_id
```